# Scrapy Crawl Spider not following links

Tags: python-2.7, web-scraping, scrapy, screen-scraping

So i wrote a web crawler to extract food items from walmart.com. Here is my spider. I cant seem to figure out why it does not follow the links on the left until. It pulls the main page then finishes.

My intended goal is for it to follow all the links on the left flyout bar then exract each food item from those pages.

I even tried just using allow=() so that it follows every link on the page but that still does not work.

```
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from scrapy.contrib.loader import XPathItemLoader
from scrapy.contrib.loader.processor import Join, MapCompose
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor as sle
from walmart_scraper.items import GroceryItem


class WalmartFoodSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "walmart_scraper"
    allowed_domains = ["www.walmart.com"]
    start_urls = ["http://www.walmart.com/cp/976759"]
    rules = (Rule(sle(restrict_xpaths=('//div[@class="lhn-menu-flyout-inner lhn-menu-flyout-2col"]/ul[@class="block-list"]/li/a',)),callback='parse',follow=True),)

    items_list_xpath = '//div[@class="js-tile tile-grid-unit"]'

item_fields = {'title': './/a[@class="js-product-title"]/h3[@class="tile-heading"]/div',
               'image_url': './/a[@class="js-product-image"]/img[@class="product-image"]/@src',
               'price': './/div[@class="tile-price"]/div[@class="item-price-            container"]/span[@class="price price-display"]|//div[@class="tile-price"]/div[@class="item-price-   container"]/span[@class="price price-display price-not-available"]',
               'category': '//nav[@id="breadcrumb-container"]/ol[@class="breadcrumb-list"]/li[@class="js-breadcrumb breadcrumb "][2]/a',
               'subcategory': '//nav[@id="breadcrumb-container"]/ol[@class="breadcrumb-list"]/li[@class="js-breadcrumb breadcrumb active"]/a',
               'url': './/a[@class="js-product-image"]/@href'}
def parse(self, response):

    selector = HtmlXPathSelector(response)

    # iterate over deals
    for item in selector.select(self.items_list_xpath):
        loader = XPathItemLoader(GroceryItem(), selector=item)

        # define processors
        loader.default_input_processor = MapCompose(unicode.strip)
        loader.default_output_processor = Join()

        # iterate over fields and add xpaths to the loader
        for field, xpath in self.item_fields.iteritems():
            loader.add_xpath(field, xpath)
        yield loader.load_item()
```

Comment: This happed to me because I modified the base template that subclasses Spider. Use the crawl template to generate a working CrawlSpider: `scrapy genspider --template crawl spider_name allowed_domain`.

Answer (score 5):

You are not supposed to override the `parse()` method when using the `CrawlSpider`. You should set a custom `callback` in your `Rule` with a different name.
Here is the excerpt from the [official documentation](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#crawling-rules):

> When writing crawl spider rules, avoid using parse as callback, since
>   the CrawlSpider uses the parse method itself to implement its logic.
>   So if you override the parse method, the crawl spider will no longer
>   work.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I ended up just writing my own link extracting methods but will change my code since this seems like it will be much easier.

Comment: i actually just did it a different way and extracted my own links then used a callback. Im sure what you mentioned was on reason mine was not working because of the built in way scrapy uses the crawl spider.